# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in reactjs application

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

I have a JS method that takes a JSON file and try to get information out of it:

```
getData(json) {
        var output = '';

        json.Legs.forEach(function (item) {
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
        });

        return output;
    }
```

I am getting this error for forEach:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Is it possible to use forEach like this or I shouldn't be using forEach at all?
Is there nother way to do this?

Comment: error is pretty much clear, you do not have data within `json.Legs`.

Comment: JSON by definition does not have arbitrary properties as it is just a string. Do you mean a JavaScript object instead or do you pass a string? How do you call that function?

Comment: You need to run each loop after checking only if json.Legs is not null. e.g if(!json.Legs){
  json.Legs.forEach(function (item) {
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
        });
}

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute loop after confirming that `json.Legs` is not null. e.g

```
if(json.Legs){
  json.Legs.forEach(function (item) {
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this as the first line in the code and see what it prints. If it is an array you can all `forEach` on it. Otherwise it's throwing the right error.

```
console.log(json.Legs)
```

Comment: Given the error message, it is obviously not an array but `undefined` ;)

Comment: it returns undefined!

Comment: Then check the content of the input `json` variable. It needs to have `Legs` property for this to work.

Comment: neat answer :)  but I think json should be caps JSON

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick (check whether .legs property exists and whether its an array before iterating):

```
getData(json) {
    var output = '';

    if(json.Legs && Array.isArray(json.Legs)){

     json.Legs.forEach(function (item) {
        //do something with item
     });
    }

    return output;
}
```